# How do you write a C program to execute another program?

Tags: c, linux

In linux, I would like to write a C program that launches another program. When the program runs, the shell will be waiting for you to input a command that you have defined in you program. This command will launch the second program.

For example, assume there is a simple C program called "hello" in the same directory as the invoking program. The "hello" program prints the output  "hello, world". The first program would be run and the user would input the command "hello." The "hello" program would be executed and "hello, world." would be output to the shell.

I have done some search, and people suggested the "fork()" and "exec()" functions. Others said to use "system()". I have no knowledge about these functions. How do I call these functions? Are they appropriate to use?

Example code with explanations would be most helpful. Other answers are also welcome. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 41):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for fork */
#include <sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* for wait */

int main()
{
    /*Spawn a child to run the program.*/
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if (pid==0) { /* child process */
        static char *argv[]={"echo","Foo is my name.",NULL};
        execv("/bin/echo",argv);
        exit(127); /* only if execv fails */
    }
    else { /* pid!=0; parent process */
        waitpid(pid,0,0); /* wait for child to exit */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `echo` in the `argv` variable and in the `execv` call?

Comment: @User, because it's argv[0], i.e. *program name*.

Comment: The redundancy might be reduced by deriving the first argument to `execv` from the first element in the `argv` array, or vice versa?

Comment: I am so confused by this. Does `execv` have some sort of conditional built into it that conditionally launched the next line of code? or does execv terminate execution at itself for some reason if it succeeds?

Are we launching a second instance of yourself? What is the point of that? We basically just create 2 threads, one waits for the second to finish executing, and the second does what we want the program to do?

Comment: I would add a check to the code above to see if `pid` is -1.  If it is -1 , then the fork creation failed and the program should exit.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)

Comment: You do not need to create a second process using `fork()`!  Just run `exec()`.  When `execv()` is called, the process from which it was called is terminated and replaced by the new process in the allocated portion of memory and with the same process ID.  If you want to execute additional statements from the parent program after the second (or child) program has finished, use `system()` instead.

Answer (score 14):

If you are new to fork, graphical representation about fork and exec might be helpful to you.

**Depiction of `fork()`**

```
  +-------------+  
  |main program |  
  +-------------+    (fork())
        |___________________________  
  +-------------+                   |
  |main program |           +-------------+ 
  +-------------+           |main program |
        |                   +-------------+  
  +-------------+                   |        (exec())
  |main program |           +-------------+
  +-------------+           |hello program|
                            +-------------+
```

As you might have already read in a tutorial, after calling `fork()` a duplicate copy of the existing program is created, and the `exec()` after that replaces that copy with the new program, which you pass to it as arguments. Two execution units for two programs will be running after `fork()`.

Answer (score 7):

Won't [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) be enough for you?

```
/* ... */
if (!strcmp(cmd, "hello")) system("hello.exe");
/* ... */
```

Comment: it's linux, so it is likely that no exe is found. Though, it can be any name.

Comment: @Vladimir: the OP states the program is "hello.c". It most likely is not -- I just wanted to point him in the right direction when he tries my snippet :)

Comment: @vissi: `<cstdlib>` is probably the C++ version; the C version is declared in `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: thanks for your quick response, could you explain a little bit more about the "system()" function, or could you show me another example of calling this function ?

Comment: @charlie: you can click the system in my post to go to a description of the function. Basically what you put inside the parenthesis is what you'd write in the shell. Your program executes that and waits until it ends.

Answer (score 0):

For the most simple case you should two compiled programs in one directory:

```
> ls
.
hello
second
```

In second program you just need to call `system("hello");`

Comment: Things don't work that way in *nix environments. system(...) invokes a shell (/bin/sh actually), which will look in the search PATH for executables ($PATH environment variable). Since one should not place the working directory (./) in PATH for security reasons, placing the callee programm in the same directory as the caller will not work. This is different from Windows, where the working directory is included in the search.

Answer (score 0):

> I have done some search, and people suggested the `fork()` and `exec()` functions. Others said to use `system()`. I have no knowledge about these functions. How do I call these functions? Are they appropriate to use?

Yes. Read first the documentation (`man` page), e.g. of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html), [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). Quite probably you have that documentation locally on your computer, using [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html). Notice that `system` uses [`sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html) (thru [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) or [dash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dash.1.html)), because it is `fork`-ing, [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-ing and [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)-ing the `/bin/sh` POSIX shell.

I think that **`fork` is difficult to understand** because on success it returns "twice". I won't try to explain it here (I'll need many pages for that). I recommend reading [fork (system call)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) wikipage at first. Then, read some good Linux programming book, e.g [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (freely downloadable).

Read also about [Virtual Address Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

You could also read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) for a more general view.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on whether you want to execute additional statements in your parent program after executing the second (or child) program.

If you want to execute additional statements in your parent program after executing your second (or child) program, I would use `system()`.

If you do **NOT** need to execute additional statements from the parent program after executing your second (or child) program, I would just use `execv()`.  A second process will NOT be created.  The parent program will terminate and the second program will run with the same process ID as the parent program.

P.S.  In this scenario, you could also use `system()`. But if you use `system()`, two processes with different process IDs will be created - one process ID for the main program and a second process ID for the second program.

In your example, you can use either the `system()` function or the `execv()` function.

Here is a simple self-explanatory example using `system()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello from the parent process\n");

    if ( system("echo 'Hello from the child process' > test.txt") != 0 )
    {
        printf("ERROR executing system() command\n");
    }

    if ( system("cat test.txt") != 0 )
    {
        printf("ERROR executing system() command\n");
    }

    printf("Executing from the parent process again!\n");
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Grinchs-MBP:Downloads rob$ ./parent3
Hello from the parent process
Hello from the child process
Executing from the parent process again!
```

Remember to include the `stdlib.h` header file, if you intend to use `system()`.

If you do **NOT** need to execute additional statements in your parent program after the child or second program has finished, I would just use `execv()` in the parent program.

In this case, you do not need to create a fork using `fork()`.  You just need to use `execv()`. If you want to use `execv()`, remember to include the `unistd.h` header file.

When `execv()` is called, the process from which it was called is terminated and replaced by the new process in the allocated portion of memory and with the same ID.

If the `execv()` executes successfully, it does not return. If it returns, it is because an error occurs.  In other words, `execv()` should be the last statement you intend to execute from your parent program since `execv()` will only return to your parent program in case of an error.

Again -- if you want to execute another program from your parent program and want to execute additional statements in the parent program after the second (or child) program has finished, then I would use `system()` instead.

Here is a simple example using `execv()`:

**Parent Process Code**

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <errno.h>

int main ()
{
printf ("I am the parent process\n\n");

char *arg_Ptr[4];
arg_Ptr[0] = "child.c";
arg_Ptr[1] = "Hello from the child process";
arg_Ptr[2] = "Good-Bye from the child process!";
arg_Ptr[3] = NULL;

execv("/Users/rob/Downloads/child.bin", arg_Ptr);
printf ( "Error:  %i\n", errno);
}
```

**Child Process Code**  (Saved at /Users/rob/Downloads/child.bin).

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 printf ("I am the child process\n");

 printf ("Argument 1: %s\n", argv[1]);
 printf ("Argument 2: %s\n", argv[2]);
 printf ("Argument 3: %s\n", argv[3]); 
}
```

**Here is the Output**

```
Grinchs-MBP:Downloads rob$ ./parent 
I am the parent process

I am the child process
Argument 1: Hello from the child process
Argument 2: Good-Bye from the child process!
Argument 3: (null)
```

Comment: That's a lot of new answer for a question from 2011.