# How to call the main() of a C program from a different C program?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

[image: Query]
This is the snippet where I call the main of another class by including its header file...
As the title says, I want to invoke the main() of a program with parameters from another C program.
Example:
Suppose there are two programs:
`imain.c` and `another.c`

I wish to call the main() of `imain.c` from the body of main in `another.c` and pass parameters..

Comment: [`man 3 exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execv.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [the second Google hit that someone couldn't be bothered to spend 2 minutes on searching for...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460421/how-to-write-a-c-program-to-execute-another-program)

Comment: @H2CO3: Although related, that's a different question.

Comment: If you paste code into your question, please paste it *as text*, not as an image -- and be sure to format it as code (indent 4 spaces or highlight it and type control-K).

Comment: okay keith..wil keep in mind.. i pasted it from a virtual box..where bidirectional pasting was off...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a header file with a function that exposes the functionality of the target main function. Then you can call that function by including that header file. A good example can be found http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm.

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you are trying to do, and what errors you are getting

Comment: i am so sorry..i cannot post the code ..company policies.. but i l post the errors right away..

Comment: Regardless of how many headers you include, you can't have more than one function called `main` in an executable.

Comment: I have pasted the code..thats the place where i call the main..which is included in one of the header files..

Comment: Your code will not compile. Like I said, declare a new function that does exactly what your main function does in another header. Then you can replace that call to main with a call to the new function. And fyi, that call to main is not a valid way to call a C function.

Comment: that will be cheating.. is there any straight forward method...as my main() program calls another 20 to 30 function.. it wont be feasible..

Comment: That's as straightforward as it gets. It's not cheating. That's how C, (and a whole host of other languages) work.

Comment: The answer is misleading. Do not use it.