# Syntax for passing a const char parameter to static char *argv[] in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, exec

Okay, I'm trying to build a daemon (for a Debian machine) that will take the command line arguments it receives (via cron) and pass them to different script files.

The daemon's `main()` is

```
 int main(int argc , char *argv[])
 {
        if(argc != 3)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        daemonize(argv[1], argv[2]);

    return 0;
 }
```

And the function daemonize has this set up

```
int daemonize(const char *cmd1, const char *cmd2) {...}
```

The troubling part in daemonize is here:

```
if (strcmp(cmd1,"sample_script") == 0)
    {
        static char *argv[] = {"/etc/init.d/sample_script", ["%s",cmd2], NULL };
        execv("/etc/init.d/sample_script",argv);
        exit(127);
    }
```

On the line

> static char *argv[] = {"/etc/init.d/sample_script", ("%s",cmd2), NULL };

I am getting this error

> initializer element is not constant (near initialization for ‘argv[1]’)

Obviously  `("%s",cmd2)` is wrong. Because using "start" works fine.

So, how do I get `cmd2` to be correctly put into `*argv[]`? Or is it something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Y do u need function parameters to be const char *

Comment: Are you sure your `argv` values are correct in `daemonize` function. Since your `*argv[] = {"/etc/init.d/sample_script", ...}` and you pass it to `execv`, so `/etc/init.d/sample_script` is repaeted twice,  Its equivalent to running as `/etc/init.d/sample_script /etc/init.d/sample_script ..` in command line. If you could provide sample input and expected output, It would be easier

Comment: What is that `[ ...]` notation inside the initializer supposed to be?

Comment: @JensGustedt thank you for your question. Basically the function daemonize will do a double forking so the the parent process is in _init_. Then it will call different scripts (depending on cmd1) and pass cmd2 to them. This way these scripts also only have init as the parent process. That's the plan anyway.

Comment: My question was more basic, the syntax that you are giving makes no sense to me. In fact you are using a *designated initializer* with a comma expression in it. This is most certainly not what you want.

Comment: @SaurabhMeshram thank you for your help. I had wondered about that too. But that's what the sample code had. **Wait!** I just had a double check of that [code] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460421/how-to-write-a-c-program-to-execute-another-program). I think I have made a mistake. This _static char *argv[] = {"start", NULL};_ compiles, but the arguements are not being passed to sample_script. It does not run. But, this _static char *argv[] = {**"sample_script",**"start", NULL};_ both compiles and runs sample_script.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
static char *argv[] = {"/etc/init.d/sample_script", ["%s",cmd2], NULL };
```

to

```
const char *argv[] = {"/etc/init.d/sample_script", cmd2, NULL };
```

You have to remove the `static` keyword. As per chapter 6.7.9, `C11` standard,

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has `static` or thread storage duration
>   shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Which says, in C language objects with `static` storage duration have to be initialized with *constant expressions* or with aggregate initializers containing constant expressions.

And, regarding *constant expression*, from chapter 6.6 of the same document

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and
>   accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

So, in `C`, a variable (name), even if declared as `const` is never a *constant expression*.

---

EDIT:

To resolve the latest issue, you can try the following

1. change `int daemonize(char *cmd1, char *cmd2) {..`
2. use `char * const argv[] = {"/etc/init.d/sample_script", cmd2, NULL };`

and you can keep the rest of the code unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that's what I originally had. But it did not work. The same error was given.

Comment: @mycowan A pointer can be made to point to another pointer during initialization and what sourav has shown is correct. I don't see a need for `NULL` here. Get rid of it

Comment: @Gopi, thanks for your help. I tried {"/etc/init.d/sample_script", cmd2};    but still the same error.

Comment: @mycowan I think we're all missing chapter  6.7.9. Let me revise once.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - thanks for the heads up. But the new error is _warning: passing argument 2 of ‘execv’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from daemonizer.c:4:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:560:12: note: expected ‘char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘const char **’_

Comment: @SouravGhosh :-( _warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]_

Comment: @mycowan did you make both the changes, `1` and `2`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh - please see user3386109's explanation of execv's declaration and his code. It worked. 

I'll give your new suggestion a try right now. Thank you.

Comment: @mycowan My idea was almost the same, minus the requirement of temporary variables. :-) Try it and let me know the result for  sure.

Comment: @SouravGhoshYour code works too! Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

The function declaration for `execv` is

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
```

The proper interpretation of the second argument is a *"`const` array of `char *`"*, which is different than an *"array of `const char *`"*. In other words, `execv` reserves the right to change the contents of the strings that the array points to, but won't change any of the pointers in the array.

Which is to say that all of the strings in the `argv` array must be in writable memory. So to be perfectly technically correct, the code should make writable copies of all the strings, like so

```
if (strcmp(cmd1,"sample_script") == 0)
{
    char arg0[] = "/etc/init.d/sample_script";
    char *arg1 = strdup( cmd2 );

    char *argv[] = { arg0, arg1, NULL };
    execv( argv[0], argv );
    exit(127);
}
```

Comment: @user3386106 - Hurry  v(^.^)v - your code worked!

I was getting a warning about _ incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strdup’_, so I had to add #include <string.h>

But - everything compiled and sample_script ran.

Thanks a whole bunch!

Answer (score 0):

you can't initialize a static with a variable/argument only known at runtime.

leave the `static` out:

```
char *argv[] = {"/etc/init.d/sample_script", ["%s",cmd2], NULL };
```

Comment: thank you for assistance, but this was the new error -  _warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]_

Comment: @mycowan, are you sure that you use a C compiler and not a C++ compiler?

Comment: To be honest, I'm pulling in bits and pieces for code from all over the place.  This project is at the very limit of my coding skill. The target machine is a stripped down linux machine (Debian - before anyone starts - the decision was made before I got here) for a remote sensing device, so I hope I'm not putting any C++ code on. I'm using gcc to compile. I hope that's the right one. (Java guy - who's only using C because the daemon will be running at the lowest run level and only C works down there - I believe)