# GTK+ dynamic array

Tags: c, gtk2

as was suggested by the other post, i'll ask new question, more specific one.

```
GtkWidget *button[] /*to be a dynamic array */

void file_folder(GtkWidget *widget,  gpointer data)
{
  GtkWidget* dialog;

  dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Choose a file", GTK_WINDOW(data),
          GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, GTK_STOCK_OK, GTK_RESPONSE_OK,
          GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(dialog);
  gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog), "/home/demo/Downloads");
  gint resp = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));


  if(resp == GTK_RESPONSE_OK)
  {
      /*select file to execute*/
      g_print("Success\n");
      gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
  }
  else
  {
      gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
  }

}
```

How can I execute the file selected

and how can I create this dynamic array which will contain:

app name, app icon and executable (assuming that I am developing on ubuntu).

Comment: I would say the next step would be to print the actual file name selected, rather than the plain `"Success"`, and to ensure you have a valid copy before closing the dialog.

Comment: the success is for test issues, instead of the print the file should execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the file name of the selected file using [`gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-get-filename).

```
gchar *filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog));
```

After obtaining the file name of the file, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5460448/3488231) and use `fork()` and `execv()` to execute the file.

As for your dynamic array, you need to use an array of a custom-defined structure. For example:

```
struct my_button {
    const char *app_name;
    GtkWidget *app_icon;
    const char *exec_path;
}
```

Then you can create a dynamic array of `struct my_button`. You can implement this yourself, and I'm sure you can find many tutorials online. Alternatively, you can use GLib (which GTK+ uses) and it provides a lot of dynamic data structures that you can use, e.g. GArray. Example:

```
struct my_button *b = malloc(sizeof *b);
b->app_name = "whatever"; // etc
GArray *arr = g_array_new(TRUE, TRUE, sizeof *b);
g_array_append_vals(arr, b, 1);
```

Remember to free the used memory after use.

For more details on GArray please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! when I use system, it gets the path and file but returns "permission denied".

Comment: @user4702146 In a terminal, type `ls -l /path/to/file`, check the first column, it should be a combination of `-`, `r`, `w` and `x`. See if there is any `x`. If no, run `chmod +x /path/to/file` in the terminal, then run your program again.

Comment: I mean, when I choose the file I want to run from the dialog (jpg, png image fop exmple) it throws Permission denied.

Comment: @user4702146 That's because image files are not executable files.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution!

```
execl("/usr/bin/xdg-open", "xdg-open", filename, (char *)0);

exit(1);
```

did the job.