# How to add, delete edit username from /etc/passwd

Tags: c, linux

I want to add or delete or edit usernames of `/etc/passwd` in a C program. Are there any standard Linux functions that do a such functions?

Comment: I don't think that there is a standard function for it (someone correct me if I'm wrong), but you can append the information to the file. See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/) for the format. Note that you need root access to read/write to this file, and be careful when playing with it, make a backup in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is `adduser` and `deluser`. Use `man deluser` for details.

EDIT: i missed the C part in the question.

`man` is also your friend in this case. With `man 3 deluser` you can ask if there is anything in stdlib called like that. Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean for more informations on that.

This is not the case. You might want to call the unix tool from within C: [How do you write a C program to execute another program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460421/how-do-you-write-a-c-program-to-execute-another-program)

Comment: Also, `useradd`, `userdel`, `usermod`. Some distros have both these and your mentioned `adduser` and `deluser`, some have one or the other. Almost all have at least one of the sets...